# Convertir un string a char en c++

Tags: c++, string

Tengo esta estructura y necesito en que en el campo nombre pueda ingresar un dato, pero ese dato lo tengo en un string.

```
typedef struct cliente{
    int cedula;
    int numCuenta;
    char nombre[100];
    cliente *izq, *der;
}cliente;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::string` tiene un método llamado `c_str()` que devuelve un puntero de tipo `const char*` a su memoria interna.

Copiar la cadena a un `char*` es algo que puede hacerse con la función `strcpy`:

```
std::string cadena = "hola mundo";
char buffer[100];
strcpy(buffer,cadena.c_str());
std::cout << buffer;
```

Por cierto, C++ **no es C**. La sintaxis que esperará la gente en C++ es esta:

```
struct cliente{
    int cedula;
    int numCuenta;
    char nombre[100];
    cliente *izq, *der;
};
```

Nota que he eliminado `typedef`. Este diseño funciona en C++ exactamente **igual** que el código que has puesto en tu ejemplo.

Answer (score 2):

segun dice Convertir un string a char en c++ hice este pequeño código que me sirvió para tal fin

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main(){

    char c[6]="ii ii";
    string letra;
    char vasinga[5];
    string v="bb bb";

    letra=c;
//    vasinga[5]==v;
    cout<<letra<<endl;

    for(int t=0; t<5; t++){

        vasinga[t]=v.at(t);

    }
    for(int t=0; t<5; t++){
        cout<<vasinga[t];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]: Si bien la respuesta, puede ser la adecuada, al no incluir un detalle con explicaciones de porque es así, puede terminar siendo cerrada. Revisa el siguiente link sobre [answer] y edita la respuesta, para mejorar la misma. También puede serte de interés realizar el [tour]